# eliminate space under heading

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://cakefacemakeup.ie/parties.html), the heading is shown on a beige background, followed by a section with a grey background.

[image]

I would like to eliminate the space underneath the title, such that the bottom of the letters are at the point where the two sections meet. I expected this to be pretty simple, probably just a matter of removing some bottom padding or margin, but I cannot figure out what is causing this space to appear under the title.

Comment: Unfortunately, It's going to be difficult to get that pixel-perfect. The way the text renders can vary depending on the browser and the user's available fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can add `margin-bottom: -18px` in `hero-h1` class

Answer (score 2):

try to change this class `hero-h1` to this:

```
.hero-h1 {
    font-size: 88px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #888888;
    line-height: 68px;
}
```

if you decrease line-height you can delete space underneath

Answer (score 2):

It's your line-height:

**CSS:**

```
.hero-h1{
    line-height: 62px;
}
```

This is what looks best in Google Chrome and Firefox on OS X. Browsers and operating systems may vary. Also, people may have different system fonts. Consider using an image instead of you really want it to stay consistent across browsers.

Another thing to note. This is your current font selection:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-family: 'Montserrat',"Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

But Arial is a much MUCH more common font. For near pixel perfection and more consistency if you don't want to go with an image, to change it to this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
    font-family: Arial, 'Montserrat',"Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Which would make your line-height this:

```
.hero-h1{
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answers about your `line-height` you can also simply change the `.hero-h1` to a block, and then set it's height to match the `line-height`

```
.hero-h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 88px;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #888888;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this method](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Hgvby/), so you do not have to play with negative margin or mind `font-size` of `H1`.

header's height is set from `line-height` , `overflow:hidden` to hide `text-shadow` overflowing..

`h1` is set as `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:bottom`. reset `margin` to 0

For the text inside `h1`, you need to set `line-height` down to `0.7`-`0.8em` to swallow gap left for letters like j,q,y.

---

**to size and tune** your `header`, play with `header` `line-height` and `h1` `font-size`.